# I have trouble connecting my Django REST api to Flutter mobile app

Tags: android, django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I'm making an Android application, that has Django REST api. Didn't have any trouble setting up the api, but I can't connect it to my application. I'm really new to it, so...

1. I tried running my app through Chrome browser. I have already disabled web security, but still I get this error:

```
unawaited(xhr.onError.first.then((_) {
      // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
      // specific information about the error itself.
      completer.completeError(
          ClientException('XMLHttpRequest error.', request.url),
          StackTrace.current);
    }));
```

No success in Android emulator either, right now I'm reinstalling it.

2. I have created database through Django models and admin. Right now it's quite simple, I need my app to get the title, annotation and image url from Shows model.
   At `for(var v in data)` line I get an error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

This is my api_handler:

```
class APIHandler {
  static Future<List<ShowsModel>> getAllShows() async {
     var uri = Uri.http(
      BASE_URL,
      "/show",
    );
    var response = await http.get(uri);
    var data = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body));
    List tempList = [];
    for (var v in data){
      tempList.add(v);
    }
    return ShowsModel.showsFromSnapshot(tempList);
  }
```

This is my Shows model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowsModel with ChangeNotifier {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? annotation;
  List<String>? image;

  ShowsModel({this.id, this.name, this.annotation, this.image});

  ShowsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    annotation = json['annotation'];
    image = json['image'].cast<String>();
  }

  static List<ShowsModel> showsFromSnapshot(List showsSnapshot) {
    return showsSnapshot.map((data) {
      return ShowsModel.fromJson(data);
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

The thing is, my api works, I can get results in postman. When my Android emulator AVD Pixel_2_API_30 was still working, Flutter could print the results in the terminal, but the results didn't show up in the app. Especially pictures, they just weren't loading. If you need some more info, I can provide. Just really need your help...

Comment: what is `response.body`? it seems its not an array...

Comment: no, it's not an array. it was just showing all the data from database that i requested. i think the problem is in map

Comment: so why are you doing: `for (var v in data){`? what do you see if you `print(response.body)`?

Comment: i was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAoYJfitObA
it used to show me all my all data from shows model, but now i only get XMLHttpRequest error when using api

Comment: fixed it, one sec

Comment: print(response.body) result:

[{"id":1,"name":"Kaija","image":"/media/images/kaija_Jr7Sjk9.jpg"},{"id":2,"name":"Mans kaimiÅÅ¡ ebrejs","image":"/media/images/ebrejs.jpg"},{"id":3,"name":"PuSHkins.DzÄ«vs","image":null},{"id":4,"name":"Anna KareÅina","image":null},{"id":5,"name":"BarikÄdes.docx","image":"/media/images/Reklamfoto_Barikades.jpeg"}]

Comment: `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body))`??? whats the reason for that `jsonEncode`?

Comment: when i just have `var data = jsonDecode(response.body);)` i have this error: 

Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)

Answer (score 0):

> At for(var v in data) line I get an error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

This is the source of your error:

```
var data = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body));
```

Assuming, your `response.body` is a valid JSON/Map (whatever you may call it),  or an array of said type, it is likely already encoded as a string, so using jsonEncode on it encases your string in another string. Due to this, the output of the `jsonDecode` results in a string when it should have been a List.

So basically, `data` is a string because of the unnecessary `jsonEncode` and since its type is dynamic you don't get the syntax error that data is not an Iterable. Rather you get the runtime error as shown above.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to `var data = jsonDecode(response.body);` and got errors from Chrome:
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'headers': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..